# Merging the view of two datatables

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I have two table having 50k data each in a database . I am using datatable of javascript to display the tables.Now its displaying two table in 2 datatable view in website.I want to display both the tables in a single table view.

Comment: Use join then to merge both table

Comment: No code, no example, no details == no answer. Stackoverflow is not a programming service where you can post wishlists.

Answer (score 0):

In that case use `server side datatable` and on the server side use `JOIN` to merge the data as per your requirement.

Ex:

```
var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: "../php/join.php",
        table: "#example",
        fields: [ {
                label: "First name:",
                name: "users.first_name"
            }, {
                label: "Last name:",
                name: "users.last_name"
            }, {
                label: "Phone #:",
                name: "users.phone"
            }, {
                label: "Site:",
                name: "users.site",
                type: "select",
                placeholder: "Select a location"
            }
        ]
    } );

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        ajax: {
            url: "../php/join.php",
            type: 'POST'
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "users.first_name" },
            { data: "users.last_name" },
            { data: "users.phone" },
            { data: "sites.name" }
        ],
        select: true,
        buttons: [
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

[Reference](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/join.html)